# Pause a python tkinter script indefinetly

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a game in `Tkinter` in which I want to implement a pause option. I want to `bind` the key <kbd>p</kbd> to stop the script. I tried using `time.sleep`, but I want to pause the game until the user presses <kbd>u</kbd>. I have tried:

```
def pause(self, event):
    self.paused = True
    while self.paused:
        time.sleep(0.000001)
def unpause(self, event):
    self.paused = False
```

However, this crashes the program and doesn't un-pause.

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You never give any opportunity to `unpause` - there is no exit from `while self.paused` so it just keeps looping!

Comment: unpause is binded to the 'u' key, so when the user clicks 'u', it sets the variable to false, breaking the loop.

Comment: Per atlasologist's answer, that isn't true

Answer (score 0):

`while` creates a loop which makes the GUI loop unresponsive to anything--including KeyPress bindings. Calling just `time.sleep(9999999)` in the pause method would do the same thing. I'm not sure how the rest of your program is structured, but you should look into the [`after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method for an easy way to add start and stop features. Here's a simple example:

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.text = Text(self)
        self.text.pack()

        self._unpause(None) # start the method

        self.bind_all('<p>', self._pause)
        self.bind_all('<u>', self._unpause)

    def _unpause(self, event):
        '''this method is the running portion. after its
        called, it continues to call itself with the after
        method until it is cancelled'''
        self.text.insert(END, 'hello ')
        self.loop = self.after(100, self._unpause, None)

    def _pause(self, event):
        '''if the loop is running, use the after_cancel
        method to end it'''
        if self.loop is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self.loop)

root = Tk()
App(root).pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried this, though it still caused the program to stall and eventually crash.

Comment: This exact code crashed, or when you implemented part of this it crashed?

Comment: This exact code is not crashing(in windows), maybe its his implementation